# How can you run iOS Apps on the Google Cloud even though it lacks support for IPv6

Tags: ios, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, ipv6, ipv4

A new app store policy by Apple has taken effect on June 1 so that *all apps submitted to the App Store must support IPv6-only networking* (https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a). How is it possible to host an app on Google Cloud Platform that only supports IPv4 (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking) and still passes Apple's review process?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. could you please write your solution step-wise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The server side of the app doesn't need to be reachable over IPv6 yet. Most IPv6-only networks have a DNS64/NAT64 service to reach IPv4-only servers from IPv6-only clients.

Take a look at [RFC 6052](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6052), [RFC 6146](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6146) and [RFC 6147](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6147) if you want to know more about the technology behind that.

This of course does make your application dependent on ugly transition mechanisms which will (probably) lower the user experience of your customers, so making sure that your servers are reachable over both IPv4 and IPv6 will make things work better. Both [Facebook](http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/blog/2015/04/facebook-news-feeds-load-20-40-faster-over-ipv6/) and [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ipv6-measurements-zaid-ali-kahn) measurements show that user experience is better from mobile networks over IPv6. The performance improvements range from 10% to 40%, depending on the mobile network.

Comment: I can confirm that this answer is correct. We running apps on the Google Cloud that supports IPv4 only at the moment and Apple allows this via DNS64/NAT64.

Comment: so what exactly is the remedy? my app is rejected for the same issue. What needs to be changed?

Comment: If the network has NAT64 then your client software only has IPv6 connectivity. When doing a DNS lookup for an IPv4 server the DNS64 will give you an IPv6 address that represents your IPv4 server. Your client application needs to connect to that IPv6 address instead, and it will reach the IPv4 server through NAT64. Make sure your application can do that. Write your application in such a way that it doesn't matter if DNS returns IPv4 or IPv6 addresses and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this is the plausible solution:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/ipv6

but before using this solution, you should set up load balancing

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/

for setting up load balancing, you need to create the instance group

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/